# thrust::reduce_by_key() returns duplicated keys

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce, thrust

Here is my code:

```
//initialize the device_vector
int size = N;
thrust::device_vector<glm::vec3> value(size);
thrust::device_vector<int> key(size);
//get the device pointer of the device_vector
//so than I can write data to the device_vector in CUDA kernel
glm::vec3 * dv_value_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&value[0]);
int* dv_key_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&key[0]);
//run the kernel function
dim3 threads(16, 16);
dim3 blocks(iDivUp(m_width, threads.x), iDivUp(m_height, threads.y));
//the size of value and key is packed in dev_data
compute_one_i_all_j <<<blocks, threads >>>(dev_data, dv_key_ptr, dv_value_ptr);
//Finally, reduce the vector by its keys.
thrust::pair<thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator,
      thrust::device_vector<glm::vec3>::iterator> new_last;
new_last = thrust::reduce_by_key(key.begin(), key.end(), value.begin(), output_key.begin(), output_value.begin());
//get the reduced vector size
int new__size = new_last.first - output_key.begin();
```

After all these code, I write the `output_key` to a file. I get many duplicated keys in the file, as below:
[image: image f console output]

So, the `reduce_by_key()` seems not work.
PS. The CUDA kernel only writes part of the `key`s and `value`s, so after the kernel some of the elements in `key` and `value` remain unchanged (likely 0).

Comment: Key sequences must be contiguous. It's entirely possible to have duplicate keys in the output if they are not adjacent in the input

Comment: I've voted to close this question.  SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in documentation:

> For each group of consecutive keys in the range `[keys_first, keys_last)` that are equal, `reduce_by_key` copies the first element of the group to the keys_output. The corresponding values in the range are reduced using the plus and the result copied to values_output.

Every  group of equal *consecutive* keys will be reduced.

So first of all you must rearrange all your keys and values so all elements with equal keys are adjacent. The simpliest method will be to use `sort_by_key`.

```
thrust::sort_by_key(key.begin(), key.end(), value.begin())
new_last = thrust::reduce_by_key(key.begin(), key.end(), value.begin(), output_key.begin(), output_value.begin());
```